# forfiles syntax issue - how to use with variables

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I've searched on here for some time but can't figure out the correct syntax for FORFILES.

```
REM here i want to give a unique name to the temp folder
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=:./" %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET dt=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)
echo %dt%
```

here is the complete code;

```
@echo on
REM WHAT IS THIS FOR?
REM i create word files on a remote shared folder. i need to move them to a 
REM local folder. Also i need to make PDF of them. if the files exist, 
REM i need to rename them like xx-R1, xx-R2 etc. up to R50 only. 
REM So this script first makes a temp folder and moves the word 
REM files there and renames them. In that temporary folder it makes 
REM pdf of the word files and then moves to the targeted folder. 
REM then must delete the temp folder. IT WORKS. I ve tried to make 
REM everything as a variable for people to benefit from it. Also you need to 
REM have the the JavaScript code called SAVEASPD.js. below i added the code 
REM i use for your reference. ONLY 1 for loop i couldnt manage below.

REM here i want to give a unique name to the temp folder
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=:./" %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET dt=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)
echo %dt%

REM create and set temp folder
mkdir "%SourceDir%\temp%dt%"
SET "TempDir=%SourceDir%\temp%dt%"

REM setting source folder:
SET "SourceDir=D:\TEST"

REM setting target folder
SET "TargetDir=D:\TEST\1"

REM listing criteria
SET "LIST=*.doc"

REM SAVEASPDF.js location
SET "JSLOC=D:\TEST"

REM ready to go...

FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%I IN ('DIR %SourceDir%\%LIST% /b') DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%TargetDir%\%%~nxI" (
        CALL :MOVEFILEFUNCTION "%%I"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :RENAMEFUNCTION "%%I"
    )
)
GOTO:FINISHING
GOTO:EOF

:MOVEFILEFUNCTION
move %1 "%TempDir%"
REM HOW TO MAKE this LOOP ??
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%g in (%TempDir%\%LIST%) do (
call cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%%g"
)
REM or;
REM FORFILES %%g /p %tempdir% /m *.doc /c "cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%%g""
GOTO:EOF

:RENAMEFUNCTION
REM if you want more enumerations, change the number "50" below to whatever you want
FOR /L %%N IN (1, 1, 50) DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%TargetDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1" (
MOVE %1 "%TempDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1"
if exist "%TempDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1" (
    call cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%TempDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1"
) else (
    GOTO:EOF
)
)
)
GOTO:EOF

REM finishing...
:FINISHING
MOVE "%TempDir%\*.*" "%TargetDir%"

REM cleaning
rmdir /S /Q "temp%dt%"

REM ===== HERE IS THE JS I USE ========

REM var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
REM var docPath = WScript.Arguments(0);
REM docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath);

REM var pdfPath = docPath.replace(/\.doc[^.]*$/, ".pdf");
REM var objWord = null;

REM try
REM {
    REM WScript.Echo("Saving '" + docPath + "' as '" + pdfPath + "'...");

    REM objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    REM objWord.Visible = false;

    REM var objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(docPath);

    REM var wdFormatPdf = 17;
    REM objDoc.SaveAs(pdfPath, wdFormatPdf);
    REM objDoc.Close();

    REM WScript.Echo("Done.");
REM }
REM finally
REM {
    REM if (objWord != null)
    REM {
        REM objWord.Quit();
    REM }
REM }
```

thanks!

Comment: The FORFILES command does not use a Token Variable like the FOR command.  I also see no reason why you should use the FORFILES command in your code.  The FOR command will be just fine and much much faster.  You can see the syntax and help for any command by typing the command name followed by a /? to see the help for the command.

Comment: Since the scope of the question changed when being edited, I suggest that you delete this question, because I think it does not help other people as, it is rather confusing as it is...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to accomplish the following:

```
forfiles /P "%tempdir%" /M "*.doc" /C "cscript.exe //nologo \"%JSLOC%\\SAVEASPDF.js\" @path"
```

or:

```
forfiles /P "%tempdir%" /M "*.doc" /C "cscript.exe //nologo 0x22%JSLOC%\\SAVEASPDF.js0x22 @path"
```

You tried to use the variable `%%g`, but there is no such variable like for the standard `for` loop command; to access the enumerated items, `forfiles` features variables indicated by the `@` sign, like `@path`, which returns the full path of an item; note that `@path` also includes the surrounding quotes `""`.

Then you need to escape any quotes you are using within the command line after the `/C` switch, like `\"`; alternatively, replace every `"` by `0x22`, which constitutes its hexadecimal character code; `forfiles` will replace it by `"` prior to execution. Actually I recommend the hex. code variant because quotes are special characters for the `cmd` instance the `forfiles` command line is running, but `cmd` does not care about the `forfiles`-specific `\"` escaping; so under certain conditions, you might receive unexpected (syntax) errors. To use a literal `\`, you should write `\\`.

Comment: thanks for @squashman and for your answers.
i edited the original post. please have a look. btw there are spaces in the folder path and the filenames either.

Comment: Have you already tried my `forfiles` command line(s)? you should describe what you want to do exactly rather than just adding more code, then it would be much easier to help you...

Comment: i tried but it prints filename as "*.doc" but the JS doesnt accept such argument. it needs to write the command lie below;
'cscript.exe //nologo \SAVEASPDF.js ANYDOC.doc'

Comment: The `forfiles` command line is commented out in your updated code, so the problem is something else! I'm pretty sure it's the `:MOVEFILEFUNCTION` block; I think you should write `for %%g in ("%TempDir%\%LIST%") do` instead of `for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%g in (%TempDir%\%LIST%) do`, and in the loop body, `"%%~fg"` instead of `"%%g"` (the `f` might be omitted, depending on your `*.js` script)...

Comment: sorry it became a bit complicated for me too. 
the problem is was in :MOVEFILEFUNCTION block exactly. 
i tried as follows;
for %%g "usebackq delims=|" %%g in (%TempDir%\%LIST%) do (
call cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%%~fg"

again to be clear, the targeted command line result is as follows;
cscript.exe //nologo "D:\test\SAVEASPDF.js" "ANYDOC.doc"

and in the loop, will continue like;
cscript.exe //nologo "D:\test\SAVEASPDF.js" "ANYotherDOC.doc"

and the JS doesnot accpet wildcards. this is the reason i try to use a for loop 
thanks.

Comment: You don't need `for /F` for this task; you are trying to walk through items `*.doc` in a certain directory; that's what plain `for` is intended for; so `for %%g in ("%TempDir%\%LIST%") do (call cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%%~fg")` should work perfectly; you even don't need the `call` command to run an external program, it's just required to call external _batch-files_...

Comment: thanks, now it is clear :) fixed the code and sent the answer for public use.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working script. thanks for all the support below.

```
@echo on
REM WHAT IS THIS FOR?
REM i create word files on a remote shared folder. i need to move them to a 
REM local folder. Also i need to make PDF of them. if the files exist, 
REM i need to rename them like xx-R1, xx-R2 etc. up to R50 only. 
REM So this script first makes a temp folder and moves the word 
REM files there and renames them. In that temporary folder it makes 
REM pdf of the word files and then moves to the targeted folder. 
REM then must delete the temp folder. IT WORKS. I ve tried to make 
REM everything as a variable for people to benefit from it. Also you need to 
REM have the the JavaScript code called SAVEASPD.js. below i added the code 
REM i use for your reference. It works fine now. 

REM here i want to give a unique name to the temp folder
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=:./" %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET dt=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)
echo %dt%

REM create and set temp folder
mkdir "%SourceDir%\temp%dt%"
SET "TempDir=%SourceDir%\temp%dt%"

REM setting source folder:
SET "SourceDir=D:\TEST"

REM setting target folder
SET "TargetDir=D:\TEST\1"

REM listing criteria
SET "LIST=*.doc"

REM SAVEASPDF.js location
SET "JSLOC=D:\TEST"

REM ready to go...

FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%I IN (`DIR %SourceDir%\%LIST% /b`) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%TargetDir%\%%~nxI" (
        CALL :MOVEFILEFUNCTION "%%I"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :RENAMEFUNCTION "%%I"
    )
)
GOTO:FINISHING
GOTO:EOF

:MOVEFILEFUNCTION
move %1 "%TempDir%"
for %%g in ("%TempDir%\%LIST%") do (cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%%~fg")
GOTO:EOF

:RENAMEFUNCTION
REM if you want more enumerations, change the number "50" below to whatever you want
FOR /L %%N IN (1, 1, 50) DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%TargetDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1" (
MOVE %1 "%TempDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1"
REM it will not loop until it reaches 50, if the file not exists, will end the script. 
if exist "%TempDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1" (
    call cscript.exe //nologo "%JSLOC%\SAVEASPDF.js" "%TempDir%\%~n1-R%%N%~x1"
) else (
    GOTO:EOF
)
)
)
GOTO:EOF

REM finishing...
:FINISHING
MOVE "%TempDir%\*.*" "%TargetDir%"

REM cleaning
rmdir /S /Q "temp%dt%"

REM ========HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT I USE=====
REM var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
REM var docPath = WScript.Arguments(0);
REM docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath);

REM var pdfPath = docPath.replace(/\.doc[^.]*$/, ".pdf");
REM var objWord = null;

REM try
REM {
    REM WScript.Echo("Saving '" + docPath + "' as '" + pdfPath + "'...");

    REM objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    REM objWord.Visible = false;

    REM var objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(docPath);

    REM var wdFormatPdf = 17;
    REM objDoc.SaveAs(pdfPath, wdFormatPdf);
    REM objDoc.Close();

    REM WScript.Echo("Done.");
REM }
REM finally
REM {
    REM if (objWord != null)
    REM {
        REM objWord.Quit();
    REM }
REM }
```